# What values can $n$ assume, when $z^2+n= x^2+y^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^2+y^2 =n +z^2$ where $x,y,z$ are different natural numbers. What values can $n$ assume?

What if x,y,z>0 considering the confusion of 0 as [natural number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any odd number : $0^2+(n+1)^2=(2n+1)+n^2$

Any positive even number : $1^2+(n+1)^2=(2n+2)+n^2$

Any negative odd number : $0^2+n^2=-(2n+1)+(n+1)^2$

Any negative even number : $1^2+n^2=-2n+(n+1)^2$

If you really need to have different numbers x y z just remark that

$5^2+11^2=2+12^2$

and $3^2+5^2= -2 + 6^2$

If you need x, y, z to be non zero for odd numbers :

$2^2+(n+1)^2=(2n-3)+n^2$ for example...
$2^2+n^2=-(2n-3)+(n+1)^2$

and for the case 1 (all different) $4^2+7^2=1+8^2$ and $4^2+8^2=-1+9^2$...

Comment: $(n+1)^2+(-2n)=n^2+1^2$

Comment: Also the negative numbers, by using $n-1$ in place of $n+1$.

Comment: We know $(r^2-s^2)+(2rs)^2=(r^2+s^2)^2$ for all integer r,s=>0 is obvious. Is 0 a natural number?

Comment: I just add the negative ones :)

Comment: "where $x,y,z$ are different natural numbers" may cause some trouble for, e.g., $2$.

Comment: Ya, I just learned about the confusion about the inclusion of 0 in the set of natural numbers which I knew to be positive integers.

Comment: The number $2$ is not much trouble even if we ask for distinctness, since $2=11^2+5^2-12^2$.

Comment: I add 2 and -2 examples for TMM in the same time as André :)

Comment: Could you please add non-zero solution for odd n

Comment: I should identified $n^2+2^2 - (n-1)^2=2n+3$ which I could thought out on my way.